# How do I multiple two columns of data together in kdb/q?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to teach myself kdb/q programming.  I can't seem to figure out how to take a simple table (columns `symbol`, `price`, and `shares`) and multiply `price * shares` to get `volume`.  I've read Q for Mortals, code.kx.com, etc and am stuck.  Could someone please give me a hint or point me in a direction of where I could figure out this simple problem!  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where t is the table name:

```
update volume: price*shares from t
```

Or

```
t: select symbol, price, shares, volume:price*shares from t
```

Answer (score 3):

checkout the [q-sql](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/) for select/update queries.

Here is the [`update`](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#95-the-update-template) statement you are after:

```
q)trade:([] symbol:5?`APPL`GOOG;  price:5?100.; shares:5?10)

q)update volume:price*shares from  trade
symbol price    shares volume
-------------------------------
APPL   21.09    6      126.54
APPL   88.22095 8      705.7676
APPL   25.0192  4      100.0768
GOOG   51.68842 1      51.68842
APPL   53.8142  8      430.5136
```

However, I'll recommend checking [Q for mortals](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/), it pretty much covers everything for Kdb+ beginner.

Comment: thanks this worked.  i've read/referenced Q for Mortals but i find it difficult to use for more complex queries.  for example, i'm trying to calculate the aggregate dollar volume per symbol and sort the results ascending by the dollar volume.  it seems i need to do this all in one query.  i have the volume column in my table now but i can't seem to figure out how to aggregate or sort asc all in the same query.  Q for Mortals hasn't been much help, but maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: give a try with this - `volume xasc select volume:sum price*shares by symbol from trade

Comment: I am glad it helped!